# get array of exam by using preg_match_all and foreach

Tags: php, regex, foreach

I need a array for the exam, but the result after using regex and foreach is not what I want.

My current result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1 Q 1.Question 1? A 0 - Answer 11
            [1] => 1 Q 1.Question 1? A 1 - Answer 12
            [2] => 1 Q 1.Question 1? A 2 - Answer 13
            [3] => 1 Q 1.Question 1? A 3 - Answer 21
            [4] => 1 Q 1.Question 1? A 4 - Answer 22
            [5] => 1 Q 1.Question 1? A 5 -  Answer 31
            [6] => 1 Q 1.Question 1? A 6 -  Answer 32
            [7] => 1 Q 1.Question 1? A 7 -  Answer 33
            [8] => 2 Q 2.Question 2? A 0 - Answer 11
            [9] => 2 Q 2.Question 2? A 1 - Answer 12
            [10] => 2 Q 2.Question 2? A 2 - Answer 13
            [11] => 2 Q 2.Question 2? A 3 - Answer 21
            [12] => 2 Q 2.Question 2? A 4 - Answer 22
            [13] => 2 Q 2.Question 2? A 5 -  Answer 31
            [14] => 2 Q 2.Question 2? A 6 -  Answer 32
            [15] => 2 Q 2.Question 2? A 7 -  Answer 33
            [16] => 3 Q 3. Question 3? A 0 - Answer 11
            [17] => 3 Q 3. Question 3? A 1 - Answer 12
            [18] => 3 Q 3. Question 3? A 2 - Answer 13
            [19] => 3 Q 3. Question 3? A 3 - Answer 21
            [20] => 3 Q 3. Question 3? A 4 - Answer 22
            [21] => 3 Q 3. Question 3? A 5 -  Answer 31
            [22] => 3 Q 3. Question 3? A 6 -  Answer 32
            [23] => 3 Q 3. Question 3? A 7 -  Answer 33
        )

)
```

In the result above, the number of times the question and answer is repeated multiple times.

My desired output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1 Q 1.Question 1? A 0 - Answer 11
            [1] => 1 Q 1.Question 1? A 1 - Answer 12
            [2] => 1 Q 1.Question 1? A 2 - Answer 13
)
[1] => Array
        (
            [3] => 2 Q 2.Question 2? A 0 - Answer 21
            [4] => 2 Q 2.Question 2? A 1 - Answer 22
)
[2] => Array
        (
            [5] => 3 Q 3.Question 3? A 0 -  Answer 31
            [6] => 3 Q 3.Question 3? A 1 -  Answer 32
            [7] => 3 Q 3.Question 3? A 2 -  Answer 33
         )

)
```

My current code ([run online](https://onlinephp.io/c/9e1ad)):

```
<?php
$re_question = "'<b>(.*?)</b>'si";
$re_answer = '#<input[^>]* value="([a-z]\.\)(.*?)")>#s';

$str = '<b>1.Question 1?</b><div class="data-check" style="padding-left:25px;"><input class="data-form-input" type="radio" name="q11111" value="a.)Answer 11">a.)Answer 11</div><div class="data-check" style="padding-left:25px;"><input class="data-form-input" type="radio" name="q11111" value="b.)Answer 12">b.)Answer 12</div><div class="data-check" style="padding-left:25px;"><input class="data-form-input" type="radio" name="q11111" value="b.)Answer 13">b.)Answer 13</div><br><b>2.Question 2?</b><div class="data-check" style="padding-left:25px;"><input class="data-form-input" type="radio" name="q11111" value="a.)Answer 21">a.)Answer 21</div><div class="data-check" style="padding-left:25px;"><input class="data-form-input" type="radio" name="q22" value="b.)Answer 22">b.)Answer22</div><br><b>3. Question 3?</b><div class="data-check" style="padding-left: 25px;"> <input class="data-form-input" type="radio" name="q33333" value="a.) Answer 31"> a.) Answer 31 </div><div class="data-check" style="padding-left: 25px;"> <input class="data-form-input" type="radio" name="q33333" value="b.) Answer 32"> b.) Answer 32 </div> </div><div class="data-check" style="padding-left: 25px;"> <input class="data-form-input" type="radio" name="q33333" value="b.) Answer 33"> b.) Answer 33 </div>';

$questions = "";
$answers = [];
$questions_and_answers = [];
$answer_number = 0;
$question_number = 0;
//question
preg_match_all($re_question, $str, $matches_question, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
//if (count($matches_question) > 0) {
foreach($matches_question as $sentence_question){
    $answer_number = 0;
    $each_question = $sentence_question[1];
    $question_number +=1;
preg_match_all($re_answer, $str, $matches_answer, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
foreach($matches_answer as $sentence_answer){
    $questions_and_answers[] = $question_number. ' Q ' .$each_question. ' A ' .$answer_number.' - '.$sentence_answer[2];
    $answer_number +=1;
}    
//$result = array_merge($questions);
$result = array_merge([$questions_and_answers]);
 
}

print_r($result);
?>
```

Can you please help me, how to solve this?

Comment: This looks very similiar to your last question, just with more examples.

Comment: Use https://3v4l.org/5Ynp0 as a starting point. This relates back to previous post.

Comment: @user3783243  thank you for your help. in result don't display value. https://i.imgur.com/9zWVcYa.png Please chekck thanks

Comment: Yes, it is a **starting point**. You should be able to build from that. It has the data points your require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the answers are nested with each question - not only foreach need to be nested, main regex also.
Try this

```
<?php

//$str = ...

// $re_question_and_answers = '@\<b\>\d+\.\s*(?P<QUESTION>.*\?)\</b\>(?P<ANSWERS>(?:\<div[^\>]*\>\s*\<input[^\>]* value\=\"[^\"\)]+\)\s*[^\"]+\"\>(?:[^\<\>]*\</div\>)+' /* note: double " </div>" after Answer 32 */ .')+)(\<br\>|$)@iU'; // or '...@simU' // GOOD! but long and inflexible/immutable for "<div>" and "</div>"
$re_question_and_answers = '@\<b\>\d+\.\s*(?P<QUESTION>.*\?)\</b\>'
    .'(?P<ANSWERS>'
    .'(?:'  // (start of 1 ANSWER)
    .'([^\<\>]*|\</?(?!b\>)[^/\>]*\>)*' /* not "<tags>", "</tags>", or tags but not "<b>", "</b>" */
    .'\<input[^\>]* value\=\"[^\"\)]+\)\s*[^\"]+\"\s*\>'
    .'([^\<\>]*|\</?(?!b\>)[^/\>]*\>)*' /* not "<tags>", "</tags>", or tags but not "<b>", "</b>" */
    .')+'   // (end of 1 ANSWER)
    .')'    // end of 'ANSWERS'
    .'(\<br\>|$)@iU';
$re_answer = '#<input[^>]* value="([a-z]\.\)(?P<ANSWER>.*?)")>#s';

$questions = "";
$answers = [];
$questions_and_answers = [];
$answer_number = 0;
$question_number = 0;


preg_match_all($re_question_and_answers, $str, $matches_question_and_answers, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
//print_r($matches_question_and_answers);
$key_number = 0;
foreach($matches_question_and_answers as $sentence_question){
    $each_question = $sentence_question['QUESTION'];
    $question_number ++;
    $answer_number = 0;
    preg_match_all($re_answer, $sentence_question['ANSWERS'], $matches_answer, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
    //print_r($matches_answer);
    foreach($matches_answer as $sentence_answer){
        $questions_and_answers[$question_number][$key_number] = $question_number. " Q $question_number." .$each_question. ' A ' .$answer_number.' - '.$sentence_answer['ANSWER'];
        $answer_number ++;
        $key_number ++;
    }
}   

echo 'Result: ';
print_r($questions_and_answers);

?>
```

Look at https://onlinephp.io/c/76493